# jquery how to get events for an item to change based on changing the class

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="show">Hello</div>
```

With script:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    $(this).addClass('pop');
   alert("show");
});
$('.pop').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('pop');
    $(this).addClass('show');
   alert("pop");
});
```

So what I was hoping would happen is you would click Hello and it would say show. Then next time it would say pop. It would then alternate between the two. However it is stuck on show.

I guess some how I need to rebind the event.

Can someone help me with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kgak9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on` instead.

```
$('body').on('click', '.show', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    $(this).addClass('pop');
   alert("show"); 
});
$('body').on('click', '.pop', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('pop');
    $(this).addClass('show');
   alert("pop");
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kgak9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

or try use toggle();

```
$('.show').toggle(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('show');
      $(this).addClass('pop');
      alert("show"); 
   },
   function() {
       $(this).removeClass('pop');
       $(this).addClass('show');
       alert("opo");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag on the element with `data` instead of using classes producing shorter code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var flag = $(this).data('flag') || false;
  alert(flag ? 'foo' : 'bar');
  $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/epilew/2/edit

**Edit:**

You can extend this to use any number of words you want taken from an array.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var words = ['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'lol'];
  var flag = $(this).data('flag') || 0;
  var word = words[flag];
  alert(word);
  $(this).data('flag', flag >= words.length-1 ? 0 : ++flag);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/epilew/4/edit